# Cannot access the docker app

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

Am working on a php docker application, am running my application in an ubuntu virtual machine from windows.I cannot see the output after running my application

My application files:-

```
index.php (has echo hello world.)
DockerFile
```

my docker file:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
EXPOSE  80
COPY . /var/www/html/app
```

I run the application and i can see the files under www/app folder in the container but I could not access the application if enter the ip address showing in the terminal in a web browser...

In web browser, i tried http://IP address/app

Please help

Comment: Try changing your copy command to be to `/var/www/html/` instead

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you for the reply, Actually i tried this...but still not working...Thanks

Comment: @NigelRen i have edited my question..Thanks

Comment: Can you please your `docker run` command? What port is being published?

Comment: @ Qasim Sarfaraz Hi, i have followed this tutorial .. https://www.javatpoint.com/docker-php-example i got the exact output in terminal but couldnot access app in browser...Also i have done this in an ubuntu virtual machine...too..